# OnlineCalculator Error Checking

Tags: javascript

I've made an online calculator program, but have run into a couple of error checking issues. This is what I want to make my program check for:
1.No two operators should be added consecutively.
2.The equation shouldn't start from an operator except minus.
3. Not more than one decimal should be there in a number.

Any help accomplishing this task would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my JavaScript portion of the code. If anyone needs my HTML portion just ask. I don't think it's essential right now though.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // Addings operators
   var operatorEl = document.getElementsByClassName('operator');
   // Adding btnElements
   var btnElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addme');
   //var to store user input and button input
   var inputVal = '';
   var buttonVal = '';
   var display = document.getElementById('display');
   var errorMsg = document.getElementById('error-msg');

   function clearContent(){
    display.value = '';
    inputVal = '';
    buttonVal = '';
    errorMsg.innerHTML = '';
   }

    operatorEl[0].onclick = clearContent;

   function backBtn() {
    var dvLength = buttonVal.length;
    buttonVal = buttonVal.substring(0,dvLength - 1);
    display.value = buttonVal;
   }

   operatorEl[1].onclick = backBtn;

   function calcCos(){
    inputVal = display.value;
    var newVal = Math.cos(inputVal);
    display.value = newVal;
   }

   operatorEl[2].onclick = calcCos;

   function calcSin() {
    inputVal = display.value;
    var newVal = Math.sin(inputVal);
    display.value = newVal;
   }

   operatorEl[3].onclick = calcSin;

   function calcSqrt(){
    inputVal = display.value;
    if(inputVal < 0){
        errorMsg.innerHTML = 'Cannot calculate the square root of a negative number.';
        display.value = '';
        //return false;
    }

    var newVal = Math.sqrt(inputVal);
    display.value = newVal;
   }

   operatorEl[4].onclick = calcSqrt;

   function calcLog(){
    inputVal = display.value;
    if(inputVal < 1){
        errorMsg.innerHTML = 'Cannot calculate the log of a non-positive number.';
        display.value = '';
        //return false;
    }

    var newVal = Math.log(inputVal);
    display.value = newVal;
   }

   operatorEl[5].onclick = calcLog;

   //When clicked the button's value will be added to the buttonVal and put into display
   for(var i = 0; i < btnElements.length; i++){
    btnElements[i].onclick = function (){
        buttonVal += this.value;
        display.value = buttonVal;
    }
   }

   function evaluate(){
    var evaluatedOutput = eval(buttonVal);
    display.value = evaluatedOutput;
   }
   operatorEl[6].onclick = evaluate;
    </script>
```

My assumption is the code for checking these 3 conditions will go somewhere in here:

```
//When clicked the button's value will be added to the buttonVal and put into display
   for(var i = 0; i < btnElements.length; i++){
    btnElements[i].onclick = function (){
        buttonVal += this.value;
        display.value = buttonVal;
    }
   }
```

It escapes me on how to actually articulate this in my program though. Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You should use flags for such purposes, it's the simplest approach.

- Use one flag that you set to false after the first character had been entered and to true again after the equal sign.
- Use one flag you set to false after one operator had been entered and to true again if the next character is not an operator. Problem: `23 + -3`
- Use one flag you set to false for the first decimal-mark and to true again after the last number (either an operator or the equal sign)

This all is quite close to the point where a [proper parser](https://github.com/zaach/jison) would be a better idea. You *will* pass that point the moment you start to implement parentheses.